# Printing specific column value from a webTable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print all the column values from a table based on a parameter. If the paramter matches then all the column values should be printed. This is not happening in my code below.

---

```
public class DynamicTableHandling extends DriverFactory {

  static String company = "ABB India Ltd.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    init_driver("chrome");
    driver.get("https://money.rediff.com/sectors/bse/power");
    extractTableValues(company);
}

public static void extractTableValues(String company) {
  //print all the column values from the table when the company name provided has matched//
    
 List<WebElement> tableRow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr"));

    for (int row = 0; row < tableRow.size(); row++) {

        WebElement colData = tableRow.get(row);

        List<WebElement> tableCol = colData.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        for (int col = 0; col < tableCol.size(); col++) {
            String result = tableCol.get(col).getText();

            if (company.equals(result.trim())) {
                System.out.print(result + " | ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Output -- ABB India Ltd. |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current method that you've `extractTableValues` has a complexity of `O(n^2)`. You can significantly optimize to have a `O(n)` by making a dynamic xpath.

Your effective code:

```
public static void extractTableValues(String company) {
    List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+company+"')]//ancestor::tr//td"));
    for (WebElement td : tds) {
        System.out.println(td.getAttribute("innerText"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABB India Ltd.
A
2090.10
2084.35
+5.75
+0.28
```

**Or Using Java 1.8:**

```
public static void extractTableValues(String company) {
    List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+company+"')]//ancestor::tr//td"));
    tds.stream().forEach(td -> {System.out.println(td.getText());});
}
```